# How to draw exact layout

Tags: minipage

I am trying to create a latex template to match exact style of some document so that I can programmatically fill it and create pdf documents with it.

[image]

What I want is bordered box with 19.5cm witdh, and 9cm height, with a horizontal line in the middle. I want to be able to write text in each side. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  TEXT 1
\end{minipage}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  TEXT 2
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

How can I specify exact size and draw line between minipages.

I don't need the hole in the middle line as shown in the picture.

Black rectangles denoted deducted text. Those parts will be filled with text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure you want to reproduce this with LaTeX? It looks awful!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need to produce lots of this and programmatically filling a latex template seems to be easiest way I could think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template using `geometry` and `tabulary` to simplify  calculations:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage[margin=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep.5em
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|C|}
\hline 
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}& 
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em} 
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}\\
\hline\end{tabulary}
\bigskip\par
\hfill\dotfill Some text \dotfill\hfill{}
\bigskip\par
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```